# How to Group a values in a Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have create table with two fields and I have populated this table. Now, I would like to group the values. How can I do this in SQL Server. My table looks like this:

[image: My Table]

Comment: Group how? By which column?

Comment: Please include the expected result also in your question.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

### try this:

```
select emp_code , max(dcr_date) dcr_date, min(dcr_date)dcr_date
from
your_table
group by emp_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group on the date column, the SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT DCR_DATE, EMP_CODE
FROM myTableName
GROUP BY DCR_DATE
```